# Jquery Mobile 1.8.2 : trapping scrollstop event

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm a (very) beginner when it comes to javascript and Jquery so please bear with me.

What I am trying to do is set up an event listener to detect when scrolling has stopped.
My understanding is that the solution has two parts:

1. A statement that sets up the listener.
2. A function that is called when the event fires.

I'm using the MobiOne development environment using Jquery 1.8.2

From the Jquery docs, I have this statement to listen for the event:

```
$('#m1-Equiv-eISOFrame').on('scrollstop',eFisoScroll);
```

`'#m1-Equiv-eISOFrame'` is the name of the element that the user scrolls.
`eFisoScroll` is the name of the function to be called when the event fires.

I've put the listening code in the environments predefined document ready handler, and
the other code in the main body of my program and.... It doesn't work. (go figure)

Tracing through the program using the debugger (with breakpoints) shows that the code is being parsed, but the scrollstop event is not trapped, and obviously my handler function never executes.

So, what am I doing wrong, or what additional things have I missed that are necessary to make this work.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

---

@Pow-lan,

Yes, I did try that modification, but it also does not work.  If I substitute 'scrollstop' with 'click' using the format you suggested; the click event does get trapped!

So, the placement of the code and the statement(s) are correct, but the 'scrollstop' event is ignored or not properly processed for some unknown reason. ARRRGHHHH.

Since I could trap the click event, I coded the trap for the scrollstop event in the function eFisoScroll just to see if code placement was the issue, but it failed there as well.

The mystery deepens...

Comment: for grins try $('#m1-Equiv-eISOFrame').on('scrollstop',function(){eFisoScroll();}); and see what you get.

Comment: Please don' create a new account for additional information. Instead edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#listfavorites').bind('scrollstop',function(){
eFisoScroll();

});
```